# Authentication required (git.drupalcode.org)

Tags: composer, 9

On Drupal 9, I want to install the [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module using Composer, but I get the following error.

> Using version ^3.4 for drupal/taxonomy_menu
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Installing drupal/taxonomy_menu (dev-3.x e89d1e8):
>   Authentication required (git.drupalcode.org): Username:

The command is waiting for a Git username/password, but two days ago the installation ran smoothly.

How can I ask for a stable version of the module?
On the project's page they write that, as of 21 May 2019, Taxonomy menu 8.x-3.x-dev is already fully compatible with Drupal 9.

This must be why `composer require` initially proposed 3.4 version and ultimately tried to install the *dev-3.x* version.

Comment: Are you trying to execute composer command in the corporate network or a network with proxy ? If yes try with open network.

Comment: That is the point. The problem only appears behind a proxy

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/299814/71454

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ask for a stable version of the module?

You can't install a stable version of Taxonomy Menu module for Drupal 9 at the moment because no such version exists.

If you look at the project page, you see the latest version is 3.4 which is marked **Requires Drupal: 8.x**.

> [image: screenshot]

So, if you want to use a stable version, you have to stay with Drupal 8 for now.

To use the dev version on Drupal 9, you can do this in `composer.json`:

```
    "drupal/taxonomy_menu": "3.x-dev",
```

Normally you should not need to authenticate to git.  It's probably a proxy issue; you might find some hints in [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder/issues/3010603).

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation inside a lando (docker local developement environment) I was able to overcome this problem by getting a new `personal_access_tokens` from https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

and running

```
lando composer config -g gitlab-oauth.gitlab.com glpat-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: It's a good answer in general, but it doesn't work for Drupal as git.drupalcode.org doesn't allow you to use personal access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also happens if [the WSL clock is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65086856/2415524). Run `date` to check. The WSL clock will become out of sync with Windows if you put your computer to sleep with [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states#sleep-state-modern-standby), which is the default in Windows 11, I think.

There are some workarounds, such as restarting WSL, or running `sudo hwclock -s`